# og:image is not showing in facebook debugger and while link sharing on facebook

Tags: facebook, image, facebook-opengraph

i am trying to get og:image for facebook link sharing.

The og:title and og:description is showing but the og:image is not showing in facebook sharing as well as in facebook debugger.

i used these meta tags in my code

```
<head>
<title>Ajmal link builder</title>
<meta property="og:title" content="OG Test Title ecommerce-shopping-cart-software"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://viralsgages.ml/images/ofHorlfldieluehmslWecommerce-shopping-cart-solution-for-your-business.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:image:url" content="http://viralsgages.ml/images/ofHorlfldieluehmslWecommerce-shopping-cart-solution-for-your-business.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:image:width" content="200" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="200" />
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:description" content="OG Test Description ecommerce-shopping-cart-software" />
<meta property="og:url" content="picsamzingfun.tk" />
</head>
<body>
<br />  
</body>
</html>
```

http://picsamzingfun.tk/ecommerce-shopping-cart-softwareofHorlfldieluehmslW

i don't know may be its some kind of cross domain image issue or something else

Comment: Your link is not to your site so I deleted it.

Answer (score 0):

The `og:url` is wrong - you cannot share a `.jpg` file as the URL as expect a different image to appear. The `og:url` must be for the `.html`,`.php`, `.asp` page - for example `http://viralgages.ml/volusion-features-and-comparison-reviewsell.html`

The `og:image` file in your code is http://www.xxxxxx.ml/images/selllWoHmuloehidffr0bb0c2891445bf8edd24fce6f179d125.jpg -  which does not exist (returns code 302). `http://www.xxxxxx.ml/images/selllWoHmuloehidf
fr0bb0c2891445bf8edd24fce6f179d125.jpg` does not exist either. If you are using pretend/example links use http://example.com/ at the start next time.